# Two altitudes CE and BD are drawn in a triangle ABC. Prove that angle AED= angle BCA

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I managed to prove that $\measuredangle ABD = \measuredangle ECD$. I know that if I prove that $\measuredangle EDB= \measuredangle ECB$, I can do the problem, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\angle BEC = \angle BDC = 90^{\circ}$$ we see that $BCDE$ is cyclic.

So $$180^{\circ} -\angle AED= \angle DEB = 180^{\circ} -\angle DCB$$

Comment: How can you conclude that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral

Comment: https://study.com/academy/lesson/cyclic-quadrilateral-definition-properties-rules.html

Comment: Thank you, it's obvious now!